# Mysql search design

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm designing a mysql database, and i'd like some input on an efficient way to store blog/article data for searching.

Right now, I've made a separate column that stores the content to be searched - no duplicate words, no words shorter than four letters, and no words that are too common.  So, essentially, it's a list of keywords from the original article. Also searched would be a list of tags, and the title field.

I'm not quite sure how mysql indexes fulltext columns, so would storing the data like that be ineffective, or redundant somehow? A lot of the articles are on the same topic, so would the score be hurt by so many of the rows having similar keywords?

Also, for this project, solutions like sphinx, lucene or google custom seach can't be used -- only php & mysql.

Thanks!

**EDIT - Let me clarify:**

Basically, i'm asking which way fulltext would provide the fastest, most relevant results: by finding *many instances of the search term* in **all** the data, or just *the single keyword* among a handful of other words.

I think a separate keywords table would be over the top for what i need, so should I forget the keywords column and search on the article, or continue to select keywords for each row?

Comment: use fulltext search, plenty of examples!!!

Comment: Almost the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553055/best-full-text-search-for-mysql

Comment: Yes, i saw that question, but it didn't really answer what i was asking, so i edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You should build the *word list* (according to the rules you've specified) in a separate table and then map it to each article in a join table, along with the number of occurrences:

```
words: id | name
articles: id | title | content
articles_words: id | article_id | word_id | occurrences
```

Now you can scan through the join table and even rank the articles by the occurrence of the word, and probably place some importance on the order in which the words were typed in the search query string.

Of course, this is a very academic solution. I'm not sure what your project requires, but FULLTEXT indexing is very powerful and you're always better off using it in most practical situations.

HTH.

Comment: Your table type need to be myIsam, depends of your join is a good solution but sometimes turn your query a bit slow. I have plenty of examples using problematic joins that turn your system slow. Be attentive when using joins. A kind of search engine I think it need to be something more alaborated...